# windows/python manipulate versioninfo during runtime

Tags: python, windows, winapi, console

I have multiple python processes running in their console output windows. I can set their console title via win32api.SetConsoleTitle(). Thats nice, but it would be even nicer to set some versioninfo strings (like description/company name/version) during runtime as that would allow me to easier differentiate between the (generic) python proceses in the taskmanager/process-explorer.

Has anybody ever done something like that.

thnx, dirkse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version Information are stored as a resource in the executable. You cannot change them during runtime.